# PyCharm: Environment variables with comma (THEANO_FLAGS)

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am currently trying to run a theano program in PyCharm, which links to a remote computer through ssh.

If we run this program on a local computer, the usage is

`THEANO_FLAGS="floatX=float32,device=gpu" python train.py IMDB 10`

But here is the problem in PyCharm:

I mannually set the env as below,

[image]

and when I run it, the error shows:

`ValueError: Invalid value ("float32,device=gpu") for configuration variable "floatX". Valid options are ('float64', 'float32', 'float16')`

Then I logged into the remote server, and the process details is

`tanhao   30033  0.0  0.0  14288  3196 pts/27   Ss+  13:33   0:00 bash -c cd /home/tanhao/github/NSC/NSC+UPA/src; env "IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS"="/home/tanhao/github/NSC" "IPYTHONENABLE"="True" "PYTHONPATH"="/home/tanhao/github/NSC:/home/tanhao/.pycharm_helpers/pydev" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"="1" "PYCHARM_HOSTED"="1" "PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8" "LIBRARY_ROOTS"="C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/-166109868;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/1548805601;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/58451930;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/-507136200;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/-771155378;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/remote_sources/-1562167050/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg!/;C:/Users/htan/.PyCharm2016.2/system/python_stubs/-1562167050;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm 2016.2.3/helpers/python-skeletons" "PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE"="1" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "THEANO_FLAGS"="\"floatX=float32,device=gpu\"" /home/tanhao/anaconda2/bin/python -u /home/tanhao/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 40241 --file /home/tanhao/github/NSC/NSC+UPA/src/train.py IMDB2 10
tanhao   30034  2.7  0.0 451756 51880 pts/27   Sl+  13:33   0:03 /home/tanhao/anaconda2/bin/python -u /home/tanhao/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 0.0.0.0 --port 40241 --file /home/tanhao/github/NSC/NSC+UPA/src/train.py IMDB2 10`

Comment: Did you try to put it without double quotes? means like this: floatX=float32, device=gpu

Comment: Thanks! Removing the quotes really works.

Comment: Glad to help you! I added the correct answer for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove the double quotes like this:

```
floatX=float32, device=gpu
```

What you insert in the value of Environments Variables is already valuated as a string.